# How to refresh view in grid view in vb.net win form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, gridview

```
Dim i As integer = 0
while i < 10 
gridview.RowCount = gridview.RowCount + 1
gridview.Row(i).Cells(0)  = i
i++
End while
```

I want to increase the grid view count each time I added a new row by the above code. But it only update the row, but it skips the existing rows in the data grid view. So the only last row placed.

Comment: That code makes no sense. It would not compile and the loop would never be entered even if it did. Try posting a coherent question.  Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Whatever code you wrote inside `while` loop should give you "_Unreachable code detected_" error.

Comment: It's just a code snippet what i used for view in button event

Comment: Look at what you posted! while i is less than zero will never run the loop since you just declared i equals zero.

Comment: sry i posted a wrong one. say suppose it is 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
gridview.AllowUserAddRows = false
Dim i As integer = 0
while i < 10 
gridview.RowCount = gridview.RowCount + 1
gridview.Row(i).Cells(0)  = i
i++
End while
```

this was working after I just put on the top
'gridview.AllowUserAddRows = false'

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do. You can always get the row count as **gridview.rowcount - 1**

Below code will rename the first column cells to the row sequence 0,1,2,3....

```
Dim rowcount as integer = gridview.RowCount - 1
Dim i As integer
for i = 0 to rowcount
gridview.Row(i).Cells(0)  = i
next
```